# Modal not updating to new item in array,firebase/react native state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend

my current issue with my react native app is that when a user wants to open a lesson (from the lessons array with each object being a lesson with a title,description,img url etc)to make it bigger through a modal, its state does not update.  What i Mean by this is that the books title,description,and other attributes won't change if you press on a new lesson.  What would be the solution to this?

```
export default function Learn() {
      const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
      const [lessons,setLessons] = useState()
      useEffect(() => {
        async function data() {
          try {
            let todos = []
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "lessons"));
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            todos.push(doc.data())
          });
          setLessons(todos)
          console.log(lessons)
          }
          catch(E) {
            alert(E)
          }
        }
    
        data()
        
      }, [])
      
      return (
        <View style={learnStyle.maincont}>
          <View>
              <Text style={{fontSize:28,marginTop:20}}>Courses</Text>
             <ScrollView style={{paddingBottom:200}}>
              {lessons && lessons.map((doc,key) => 
              <>
             <Modal
    animationType="slide"
    transparent={true}
    visible={modalVisible}
    onRequestClose={() => {
      Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
      setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
    }}
  >
    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
      <View style={styles.modalView}>
        <Image source={{
          uri:doc.imgURL
        }} style={{width:"100%",height:300}}/>
        <Text style={{fontWeight:"700",fontSize:25}}>{doc.title}</Text>
        <Text style={{fontWeight:"700",fontSize:16}}>{doc.desc}</Text>
        <Pressable
          style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
          onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
        >
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
        </Pressable>
      </View>
    </View>
  </Modal>
          <LessonCard setModalVisible={setModalVisible} title={doc.title} desc={doc.desc} img1={doc.imgURL} modalVisible={modalVisible}/>
              </>
              )}
             <View style={{height:600,width:"100%"}}></View>
             </ScrollView>
              </View>
        </View>
      )
    }
```

What it looks like:
[image: what it looks like before you press modal]
[image: after you press modal]

**image 1 is before you press the modal and the 2nd one is after
**the main issue though is that if you press cancel and press on another lesson the modal that opens has the the same state(title,imgurl,anddesc) as the first lesson and does not change.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you create a lot of modal windows through the map function, I suggest making one window and passing the key as a parameter and using it to search for a specific array of data that is shown to the user (photo, title, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all 3 `Modal`s are controlled by the one state variable. So when the code sets `modalVisible` to `true`, *all 3* modals are being opened at once.

You can fix this in a few ways, but a simple way would be to move the `Modal` and its state into the `LessonCard` component. This way each modal will have its own state that's only opened by its card. So the loop in `Learn` will just be:

```
 {lessons && lessons.map((doc,key) => (
     <LessonCard lesson={doc} key={key} />
 )}
```

**Adding to address question in comments**

`LessonCard` should not accept `setModalVisible` or `modalVisible` props. The

```
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
```

should be inside `LessonCard`, not `Learn`. That way each Card/Modal pair will have its own state.

Additionally, although React wants you to pass the `key` into `LessonCard` in the `map` function, `LessonCard` should not actually use the `key` prop for anything. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys

So, the `LessonCard` declaration should just be something like

```
export default function LessonCard({lesson}) {
```

Comment: it still does not work and keeps showing me on the same lesson title,descriptiom,imageUrl,etc

Comment: @YefimBlokh what does your updated `LessonCard ` code look like?

Comment: for some reason i cant comment because its too long but heres the github link to the LessonCaard component: https://github.com/yefim94/EVENNTII_WEB3APP/blob/main/components/LessonCard.js

Comment: for some reason this same error keeps persisting even in the other main components of my app even though i pass the key to the modal...

Comment: @YefimBlokh I added to my answer to address your updated code